# How to load the model from my architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, h5py, encoder, decoder

I have done this code and I need to load the model to work later on it but when I try to use load_model() the error is No model found in config file. And when I try to load the weights the error is Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.

This is my code

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

I defined an encoder and a decorder that I will use later in

```
class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
            reconstruction = decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= 64 * 64 * 3
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
            kl_loss *= -0.5
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }
    
    def test_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
            reconstruction = decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= 64 * 64 * 3
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
            kl_loss *= -0.5
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }
```

Finally this is how I use it and create the model

```
model_name = 'car_racing_VAE.h5'

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

checkpointer = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_freq='epoch')

history = vae.fit(train, train,
                epochs=150,
                batch_size = 128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(val, val), validation_batch_size=128,
                callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

So, how can I load the model and use it later?

```
model = load_model(model_name)
vae.load_weights(model_name)
```

None of them are  working

Comment: So where is your encoder path? And can you pls attach the error u encounter?

Comment: what is the full path you used to save the model? Take a look in that location and see if the .h5 file is there.

Comment: The .h5 file is where is the project. I tried to create a folder and call it so I tried vae.load_weights(model_name) and vae.load_weights('/tmp/my_model.h5'). The error I get is `Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.` Or `No model found in config file.` when using `model = load_model('my_model.h5')`

Answer (score 0):

As per the error it looks like issue with the loading the saved model from the path.

As suggested by Gerry P in comment check the location of saved model and load it from the same location.

You can use the below code to avoid the location issue.

```
#saving model
model = ...  # Get model 
model.save('path/to/location')

#loading the model back
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```